# Simple SOAP example

Tags: php, soap

Hey!
I don't really understand what soap is but it doesn't matter. I need to make some soap site that redirect to normal site or have simple content in it like 'test'.

I will need to acces it by soap://  ---- is it ever possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Never good idea to use something that you classify as "I don't really understand what soap is but it doesn't matter"

http://www.w3schools.com/SOAP/soap_intro.asp

Go through it its quite good and simple
And yea its not possible at least to my knowledge

And if you do not feel like clicking link this might help (from w3schools.com)

What is SOAP?

- SOAP stands for Simple Object Access Protocol
- SOAP is a communication protocol
- SOAP is for communication between applications
- SOAP is a format for sending messages
- SOAP communicates via Internet
- SOAP is platform independent
- SOAP is language independent
- SOAP is based on XML
- SOAP is simple and extensible
- SOAP allows you to get around firewalls
- SOAP is a W3C recommendation

Answer (score 2):

No it's not really possible. Yes, it does mater if you understand what SOAP is.

You can't redirect from a SOAP "site" to a "normal" site. That's because there are no SOAP "sites". SOAP uses XML that is not able to be parsed by a web browser. The web browser needs to do the redirecting.

If you mean to say that you want a certain URL that runs a SOAP service to redirect web browsers to a different page, then you'll have to look reading the user agent, and giving the appropriate response.

This is in fact a useful and good idea if you are developing a SOAP service, but it doesn't sound like that's what you are doing.

Comment: No, I am playgin some sort of hack-me game and thought that this will work, but I can see that not.

Comment: What do you mean by work? You've not stated your intent. Car analogy: How do I make my car go faster? vs. Can I put bigger wheels on my car? One question has the end goal in mind. The second the asker tried to be smart and thought bigger wheels = faster. If you tell us your end goal, then maybe we can help.